# Image slider with multiple images

Tags: jquery

I have multiple images in HTML File. I want to show only 5 images first. Then click on next arrow will display next 5 images and fadeOut the original ones and so on until all the images get exhausted. Similarly for prev arrow will display prev 5 images and so on until we reach to first image.

```
<ul class="thumbs noscript">

<li>
    <a class="thumb" id = "26">
        <img src="images/1.png" alt="Title #0" width="75" height="75"/>
    </a>

</li>

<li>
    <a class="thumb" id = "28">
        <img src="images/2.png" alt="Title #0" width="75" height="75"/>
    </a>

</li>

<li>
    <a class="thumb" id = "25">
        <img src="images/3.png" alt="Title #0" width="75" height="75"/>
    </a>

</li>

<li>
    <a class="thumb" id = "3000">
        <img src="images/4.png" alt="Rice" width="75" height="75"/>
    </a>

</li>

<li>
    <a class="thumb" id = "1">
        <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="Pickles and Sauces" width="75" height="75"/>
    </a>

</li>

<li>
    <a class="thumb" id = "53">
        <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="Tea and Coffee" width="75" height="75"/>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="thumb" id = "3">
        <img src="images/6.png" alt="Title #0" width="75" height="75"/>
    </a>

</li>

<li>
    <a class="thumb" id = "30">
        <img src="images/7.png" alt="Title #0" width="75" height="75"/>
    </a>

</li>

<li>
    <a class="thumb" id = "20">
        <img src="images/8.png" alt="Title #0" width="75" height="75"/>
    </a>

</li>

<li>
    <a class="thumb" id = "56">
        <img src="images/9.png" alt="Detergent Powder" width="75" height="75"/>
    </a>

</li>

<li>
    <a class="thumb" id = "27">
        <img src="images/10.png" alt="Title #0" width="75" height="75"/>
    </a>

</li>
<ul>
```

There are multiple resources for one image at a time. but didn't any with multiple images. If will be very helpful if someone can share the thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done any extensive research on this, but you might want to take a look at bx slider's carousels.

http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified

Comment: This is simply awesome. Something what I was searching.

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to call the class of bxslider like this.

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  minSlides: 5,
  maxSlides:5,
  slideWidth: 250,
  slideHeight: 250,
  slideMargin: 25,
  controls: true,
  pager: false,
});
```

to define slide limits and width height of images.